# The number of numbers lying between 1 and 200 which are divisible by either of 2 , 3 or 5?

Tags: number-theory

The number of numbers lying between 1 and 200 which are divisible by either of two , three or five?

Comment: Hint: Use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Hint :could you know the numbers of primes lie beteween $1$ and$ 200$ ,except $2,3,5$ ? (distribution of primes between $1$ and $200 $

Comment: possible duplicate to :http://math.stackexchange.com/q/152015/230303

Answer (score 2):

A)numbers divisible by 2: $\frac{200}{2} = 100$

B)numbers divisible by 3: $\frac{200}{3} = 66$

C)numbers divisible by 5: $\frac{200}{5} = 40$

counting twice

AB)numbers divisible by 6: $\frac{200}{6} = 33$

AC)numbers divisible by 10: $\frac{200}{10} = 20$

BC)numbers divisible by 15: $\frac{200}{15} = 13$

counting 3 times

ABC)numbers divisible by 30: $\frac{200}{30} = 6$

Total of numbers  = A + B + C - AB - AC - BC + ABC = 100 + 66 + 40 - 33 - 20 - 13 + 6 = 146

Comment: why you don't include the numbers divisible by 7 ?

Comment: Nice example of inclusion-exclusion

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The question didn't ask about multiples of $7$.

Comment: @Conrado costa sir the answer in the book is 145 ? That is why i am getting confused how to approach ?