# Least number of multiples of 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 in an interval

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many multiples of 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 or 13 can at least be found in intervals [j, k] if j = 10n (n > 1) and k = j + 100?

My approach is by counting with case differentiation, but not by inclusion/exclusion as this leads to far too bad (i.e. conservative) estimates.

Every interval [j, k] has 101 natural numbers, since j and k are included.

Multiples of 2: There are exactly 51 multiples of 2 since 10n and 10n+100 are both divisible by 2 i.e. {10n, 10n+2, 10n+4, 10n+6, ..., 10n+100}.

Multiples of 3: There are either 33 or 34 multiples of 3. We look at the three possible cases:

Case 1: 10n = 0 mod 3. If the interval starts with a number that is divisible by 3, we have 34 multiples of 3.

Case 2: 10n = 2 mod 3. If the interval ends with a number that is divisible by 3, we also have 34 multiples of 3.

Case 3: 10n = 1 mod 3. In this case we have only 33 multiples of 3.
Every alternate multiple of 3 has already been considered counting the multiples of 2. Thus, for Cases 1 & 2 we have 17 numbers, and for Case 3 at least 16 numbers that are multiples of 3 but not multiples of 2.

Multiples of 5: There are 21 multiples of 5 because L and R are both divisible by 5. Again, there are multiples which have already been considered in the list of multiples of 2 and 3.
Out of the 21 multiples of 5 there are 11 multiples of 2 {10n, 10n+10, 10n+20, ..., 10n+100} that were already counted.
Out of these, for 
Case 1: there are 3 odd multiples, i.e. {10n+25, 10n+55, 10n+85} already considered,

for Case 2: there are 3 odd multiples {10n+15,10n+45,10n+75} already considered,

for Case 3: there are 4 odd multiples {10n+5, 10n+35, 10n+65, 10n+95} already considered.

For Cases 1 and 2 the multiples of 5 that are not divisible by either 2 or 3 are 21–11–3 = 7. 
For Case 3 the they are 21–11–4 = 6.

Until now we have found that 51+17+7 = 75 multiples of 2, 3 or 5 will be available for Cases 1 & 2 and 51+16+6 = 73 multiples for Case 3.

Multiples of 7:
There are either 14 or 15 multiples of 7 in the interval: If 10n = {0, 5, 6} mod 7 there are 15 multiples, otherwise if 10n = {1, 2, 3, 4} mod 7 there are 14 multiples of 7. 
Again, we considered multiples of 7 when counting multiples of 2, 3 and 5. Numbers that are divisible by 7, but not by 2, 3 or 5 are 7x7 = 49, 7x11 = 77, 7x13 = 91, 7x17 =119 etc. From trying, it seems that there are at least 3 such multiples and at most 5 such multiples of 7.

And here is my problem:
Why is this and how can I show it systematically? And then, not to forget, I have to do the same with 11 and 13, i.e. find all the multiples that are not divisible by the preceding smaller primes. How can this be done systematically without compromising on the accuracy of the estimate? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you will find interesting the Euler totem function. $\varphi(n)$ is the number of coprime integeers every consecutive n numbers.

Comment: Let $x(m)$ be the number of multiples of $\ 2\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 11\ 13\ $ in the integer interval m..(m+100). Are you asking about $\ \min(\,x(10*n) : n=2\ 3\ \ldots\,)\ $ ?

Comment: I am asking for an extension to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152015/numbers-till-400-divisible-by-2-3-5-7

Comment: Again: To everybody: This is a problem posed in the Bundeswettbewerb Mathematik in Germany, solutions to be turned in September first 2019. I kindly request that nobody will take part in the discussion until then and that any discussions will be deletet until then. (converting a deleted answer from the low quality queue into a comment)

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thank you for your notice. I wasn't aware this problem was posed in a German math contest until I just saw your comment here & with my answer. I've just deleted my answer, and will not undelete it until after Sep. 1, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the principle of inclusion-exclusion, such as described for dealing with multiples of $2,3,5$ in the [Counting integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Counting_integers) section of the Wikipedia article. In particular, I would use this to determine how many integers are multiples of $2,3,5,7,11,13$ up to $k = j + 100$ and subtract the number of integers of theses multiples up to $j - 1$.

Let $f(n)$ be a function giving the number of integers which are multiplies of $2,3,5,7,11,13$ from $1$ to $n$, inclusive. Then the result you want is $f(k) - f(j - 1)$. As for determining $f(n)$, with $6$ prime factors, it is somewhat long & messy to determine. For a description of how to determine it for $4$ values, the answer by [Rick Decker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/36993/rick-decker) in [Numbers till 400 divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152015/numbers-till-400-divisible-by-2-3-5-7) does a good job of explaining it. As stated:

> ... you add the sizes of the sets, subtract the sizes of the two-set intersections, add the sizes of the three-element intersections, and so on.

Continuing, you would subtract the sizes of the four-element intersections, add those for $5$ and subtract those of $6$. Also, note the number of elements which are a multiple of $d$ from $1$ to $n$ is given by $\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \rfloor$, i.e., use the floor function which gives the largest integer $\le \frac{n}{d}$.

This is basically what you're doing using various cases, but you can use what I've described to more systematically get, as described in the answer I'm referencing, if $S_i$ is the set of set of integers divisible by the $i$'th prime from $1$ to $n$, then

\begin{align}
f(n) & = \; \mid S_1 \mid+\mid S_2 \mid+\mid S_3 \mid + \mid S_4 \mid  + \mid S_5 \mid  + \mid S_6 \mid \\
& - \mid S_1\cap S_2\mid-\mid S_1\cap S_3\mid-\dots-\mid S_5\cap S_6\mid \\
& + \mid S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3\mid+\dots+\mid S_4\cap S_5\cap S_6\mid \\
& \ldots \\
& - \mid S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3\cap S_4\cap S_5\cap S_6\mid \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align}

As for the values are in the above equation, for example, $\mid S_1 \mid = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ as the first primes is $2$, $\mid S_1\cap S_2\mid = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{6} \right\rfloor$ since the intersection of the set of multiples of $2$ and set of multiples of $3$ are the multiples of $2 \times 3 = 6$, $\mid S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3\mid = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{30} \right\rfloor$ since $2 \times 3 \times 5 = 30$, etc.

In summary, for $j = 10n$, with $n \gt 1$, and $k = j + 100$, the number you are looking for is $f(k) - f(j - 1)$.

Comment: I tried inclusion/exclusion but the estimates I get are far below what is possible since one  calculates an undifferentiated worst case. As an example from the above,  there are 16 or 17 multiples of 3 (that are not multiples of 2) or 6 or 7 multiples of 5, depending on the "case". But they need not occur simultaneously as one would assume using inclusion/exclusion. A very accurate discrimination of these cases seems therefore very important

Comment: @GeoffreyCalm If used correctly, the principle of inclusion/exclusion will give you the correct answer. As my answer states, you need to calculate the number for the upper bound, i.e., $k$, and subtract the value for one less than the lower bound, i.e., $j - 1$. The principle of inclusion/exclusion does handle the various cases, in that it will first include all multiples of the set of primes. Since this counts those values which are multiples of $2$ of these primes, these are excluded. Next, this exclusion also removes those which are multiples of $3$ of these primes, so they need to be ...

Comment: @GeoffreyCalm included back. Next, this will then add back the ones which are multiples of $4$ of these primes, so they need to be excluded again. And so on, with inclusion for each set of an odd number of primes and exclusion for an even number of primes, up to excluding those for $6$ primes, as my (1) shows.

Comment: @GeoffreyCalm As you can see from the format of (1), the number of values is actually relatively large. In the first line, there are $6$ values, the second line has $6$ choose $2 = 15$ values, up to just $1$ value at the end. Altogether, there are $63$ values (i.e., $2^6 - 1$) to first determine, then add or subtract. Using Excel, or any other computer system, to do this is not too difficult, but I suggest you start with a smaller number, e.g., just $3$ or $4$ primes, and get that working first. Then when you're satisfied, extend it to all $6$ primes.

Comment: @GeoffreyCalm Note using the minimum and/or maximum values for the singletons, duals or anything else like that won't always work properly, as you've noticed. Instead, you should use the difference in the floor function values, as I've stated & so has the linked answer. For example, with $n = 101$, you get $\left\lfloor \frac{101}{2} \right\rfloor = 50$, $\left\lfloor \frac{101}{3} \right\rfloor = 33$, $\left\lfloor \frac{101}{5} \right\rfloor = 20$, etc. If you use this specifically, you should *always* get the correct values, i.e., it'll never be a case of not a "close enough shave".

Comment: Again: To everybody: This is a problem posed in the Bundeswettbewerb Mathematik in Germany, solutions to be turned in September first 2019. I kindly request that nobody will take part in the discussion until then and that any discussions will be deletet until then. (converting a deleted answer from the low quality queue into a comment)

Comment: @YuiToCheng As it's now Sep. $2$, $2019$ in Germany, I've undeleted my answer.